# unable to use html form post in php

Tags: html, forms, post

Hello i have an html form and i'm posting data but i'm unable to get the posted data on a php page (same page)
can you please help me.
thanks in advance

```
<div class="left">
<form name="form_signin" method="post" onsubmit="return signinValid();" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="email" length ="40">
            </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Mot de Passe :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" id ="pass" length ="40">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Connexion" length ="40">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>


</form>
```

```
<?php
include 'includes.php';
include DB_CONNECT_FILE;
//session_start();
print_r($_POST); // prints an empty array even if fields are filled

$smart->assign('tpl_file',TEMPLATES_DIR.'signin.html');
$smart->display(TEMPLATES_DIR."with_right.html");

include DB_DISCONNECT_FILE;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form element needs to have an *action* attribute defined, even if the form is just reposting to the same page. According to the W3C spec, it is a required attribute:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

I'm suprised this line isn't throwing an error:

```
$smart->assign('tpl_file',TEMPLATES_DIR.'signin.html');
```

As far as I'm aware, you can only use comma seperation when echo-ing.

**UPDATE** 
Can't believe I missed it the first time around! You'll need to add the *name* attribute to the input elements. They can be the same as the *id* attribute for the element in question:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="40">
```

Also, there is no such attribute as *length*. There is *maxlength*, but I suspect you mean to use *size*.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i've changed the form line to 
    <form name="form_signin" method="post" action ="signin.php" onsubmit="return signinValid();" >

but still have the same problem.. my filenane is 'signin.php'

Comment: page reaload ok $_post=array()

Answer (score 0):

Check what is doing that javascript. It could be returning false (in this way you are preventing the post) or stopping the propagation. At first try deleting that onsubmit.