# pass values from html to php document

Tags: php

i have a table with numbers in an html document and a user can select these numbers.I have a button too.I want to send these numbers to a php document when the user press the button.Which way is the best to send these values to php document ?

Comment: Use a `<form>`? What you're asking is essentially PHP 101...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to use html form post in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792160/unable-to-use-html-form-post-in-php)

Comment: every time you dont know how many numbers the user clicked.How can i use get method when i dont know the number of selected values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax for this and fire it when the button is clicked. Use you number as the id of the button and send the id of the clicked button to php file. This way you only have to write that code once.

Answer (score 0):

The two main options are:

1. Submit an HTML FORM element - causing a page refresh.
2. Perform an AJAX call - allowing async processing of the request

Comment: can i use ajax to send the values to my php document ?

Comment: Yes. Ajax performs an HTTP request (GET / POST / etc). Just direct it at your PHP endpoint, and receive the (json?) data there.

Comment: i have to use json ??

Comment: No. But it is the standard data format for these things today.